# How to disable graphics hardware acceleration in Firefox?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, gpu, compatibility, hardware-acceleration

Firefox doesn't render properly on some systems (Ubuntu 22.04 + X/Wayland), but disabling GPU HW acceleration mitigates the problems.

How do I turn off hardware acceleration in Firefox (without using the in-browser `about:settings` method)?

Is there a config file that Firefox picks up?

Answer (score -1):

You can create a `user.js` in the Firefox profile folder to force any settings you desire.  This includes disabling GPU hardware acceleration.

Simply create an empty file in the Firefox profile folder, and name it `user.js`.  Now, add the required `about:config` settings in the same format as in `prefs.js`.  This way, you won't have to use the in-browser `about:settings` method.

Specifically, add:

```
user_pref("browser.preferences.defaultPerformanceSettings.enabled", false);
user_pref("layers.acceleration.disabled", true);
```

Save the `user.js` file, and restart Firefox.  Voilà!

Comment: Under "default" Ubuntu snap firefox I found `~/.mozilla/firefox/cx3a9c6c.default-release/` is this the profile folder?

Comment: @Moberg In Firefox's address bar, type `about:profiles` to see the path(s) to your Firefox profile folder(s).

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain what's wrong with this answer? Downvoting quality answers without an explanation is a good way to damage our community and ensure no one gets the help they want.

Comment: it's difficult to use the browser when the graphics are broken :/

Comment: Is it possible to create a system config that all profile configs are based upon? How does one distribute default configs to different users on multiple machines?

Comment: @Moberg There is no need to use the browser.  Use a text editor to create `user.js`.  Then start the browser.  Done.

Comment: @Moberg As far as creating a system config that can be distributed, you can simply copy `user.js` to each machine, or use group policies.

Comment: It's hard to use the browser to access `about:profiles` ("In Firefox's address bar, type about:profiles")

Comment: yes, we can distribute the file, but where do we put it? the profile folder seems to have a random_sequence of alphanum (`xxxxxxxx` -> `cx3a9c6c`)